# In Rails 3, where to put .js.erb files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have some small bits of JavaScript which are easier and clearer if they are part of an .erb, that is, foo.js.erb. Where should I place such files? I can see my code nicely working if I put the relevant lines right in the .html.erb file, but that is probably not a great idea.

In other words, this is not a great idea:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#reports').bind('show', function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'reports-navlist')
        $.ajax({
          url: '<%= program_reports_path(@program) -%>',
          data: { toggle: "tab" }, 
          success: function(html){
            $("div#report-html-content").html(html);
          }
        })
    });
  });
</script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="reports">
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="pill">Trend lines for all questions</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="pill" id="reports-navlist">Summart of all queries</a>
        </li> 
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="pill">Trend lines for all questions</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="pill">Details on all questions</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span10" id="report-html-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What's the best practice here?

Comment: Just put in the same controller's name directory with the action name you're calling as JS. It's same as putting an html.erb file.

Comment: It's not being triggered by an action particularly, I really want it to be part of one view. I.e. equivalent to putting it literally into the .html.erb file.

Comment: Are you handling format response in your controller's code? Can you post your `program_reports` action's code written in controller?

Comment: I can but again, it works just fine if I put the js directly in the html.erb file. But anyway, do you mean the controller that is run when I call program_reports_path(@program) from the js script?

Comment: yes, and you can just post the method you are calling to, whole controller's code isn't required.